# Can I embed Futura to my web site and distribute the file through CSS code?

Tags: fonts

I would like to use Futura on my web page.

I want to embed the font using:

```
 font-family: 'Futura';
 src: url('future.eot')
```

(or equivalent.)

I've tried searching on the internet extensively to see if this is ok regarding licences and royalties but could not figure it out.

My question is, can I do it? Is it ok legally? If not, which other free font would you recommend?

Comment: This site is for questions about the document preparation system TeX (and its formats such as LaTeX and ConTeXt).  As it stands, your question doesn't involve TeX and so is likely to be closed as off-topic.

Comment: I flagged this question for migration to [so].

Comment: I've asked the SO mods: this would be off-topic for them too (legal question, at least in part).

Comment: I read Tex as TEXT. I am a stupid foreign moron, excuse me! Which board would make sense for this Q though?

Comment: @JosephWright: Thanks for letting me know this way, that's a good idea following the discussion on meta. I'll add a note there. I agree about the mod's decision, I failed to see that this question is really mostly of legal nature. (For which there is no Stack Exchange site afaik.)